# How can I convert an API response to objects of any type in Kotlin using Retrofit?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room, dao

I'm working on an application with **about 100 different tables** in the room database.

This application must periodically search the server for possible changes in **any of those 100 tables** from a given date. To do this, a request is launched to the API using Retrofit.

My idea is to receive that response and map it to an object called `Crud`, and then do the corresponding operation with each table, regardless of what tables there are at that moment (create, read, update, delete), using for them an interface `BaseDao`. The response could contain data for any of the 100 tables.

This is an example response:

```
{
  "haveData":true,
  "crud":[
    {
      "LHPsalmodyJoin":{
        "create":[
          {
            "groupID":100030203,
            "theType":1,
            "crud":"c"
          },
          {
            "groupID":102030206,
            "theType":0,
            "crud":"c"
          }
        ],
        "update":[
          {
            "groupID":100030203,
            "theType":1,
            "crud":"c"
          }
        ]
      },
      "LHPatristic":{
        "update":[
          {
            "groupID":108002301,
            "crud":"u"
          }
        ],
        "delete":[
          {
            "groupID":108001801,
            "crud":"d"
          },
          {
            "groupID":108001901,
            "crud":"d"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see:

- in the table `LHPsalmodyJoin` two rows must be inserted and one row must be updated
- in the table `LHPatristic`  one row must be updated and two rows must be deleted.

This is the `Crud` class that this API response maps to:

```
class Crud {
    val lastUpdate: String = ""
    val haveData = false
    val crud: List<Any> = emptyList()

    //Loop in the crud property 
    //calling the corresponding BaseDao method for each object
}
```

This is `BaseDao`:

```
interface BaseDao<T> {

    @Insert
    fun insert(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg obj: T)

    @Update
    fun update(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun update(vararg obj: T)

    @Delete
    fun delete(obj: T)

    @Insert
    fun delete(vararg obj: T)
}
```

#### The problem

My problem is that the response does not map to objects of **any type**.

Instead of mapping to objects of type **`LHPsalmodyJoin`** and **`LHPatristic`** for this case, it is being mapped to a`LinkedTreeMap` object, as you can see in this inspector image:

[image]

How can I map this response to their respective objects, to pass it to the corresponding `BaseDao` method?

Comment: you can customize serialization it with type adapters, what library do you use?

Comment: @VladGuriev I'm using Moshi.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://proandroiddev.com/moshi-polymorphic-adapter-is-d25deebbd7c5) can help